# How to autocomplete an input field when live search result is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have an input field which can be used for live search and result will be shown inside a table .Created using ajax,PHP and jquery.

The live results from database is displaying fine.But I don't know how to make the field autocomplete when the user clicks on result.

here is the html code for input field and the live search result.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Executive Name</label>
<input type="text" id="search_text" name="search_text" 
 placeholder="search name" class="form-control">

<div id="result"></div>                              
</div>
```

This is the jquery and ajax script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       load_data();

       function load_data(query){
           $.ajax({
               url:"backend/livesearch.php",
               method:"POST",
               data:{query:query},
               success:function(data){
                   $("#result").html(data);
               }
           });
       }

       $("#search_text").keyup(function(){
           var search=$(this).val();
           if(search!==''){
               load_data(search);
           }
           else{
               load_data();
           }
       });


    });
```

The php page "livesearch.php"

```
<?php require 'connect.php';
    $output="";
    if(!empty($_POST['query'])){
        $search= '%'.mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['query']).'%';
        $query="SELECT id,name FROM users WHERE name like '$search'";
        $result= mysqli_query($link4, $query);
        $output .="<div class='table-responsive'>
                  <table class='table table-bordered table-sm'>
                  <tbody>";
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){

          while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
              $output .="<tr class='search-cell'>
                      <td>".$row['name']."</td>
                      </tr>";
          }
          $output .="</tbody></table></div>";
        }
        else{
            $output .="<tr><td>No Result !</td></tr></tbody></table></div>";
        }
    }

    echo $output;
    ?>
```

Comment: AJAX nor jQuery are languages. AJAX is a technique and jQuery is a library.

Comment: Also, you should use `<ul>` and `<li>` or `<select type='list'>` instead of `<table>` in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an `onclick` attribute to the `<td>` elements in your PHP like this:

```
$output .="<tr class='search-cell'>
                  <td onclick='document.getElementById(\"search_text\").innerHTML =
                  this.innerHTML'>".$row['name']."</td>
                  </tr>";
```

Let me know if it works, I have no quick way of testing it.

Comment: can't we use jquery inside html .I am just beginner sorry.?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. When I made some changes in the answer posted by @Boltkey
thanks for helping.

```
   $output .="<tr class='search-cell'>
              <td onclick='document.getElementById(\"result\").style.visibility=\"hidden\"; 
              document.getElementById(\"search_text\").value=this.innerHTML';>
             ".$row['name']."</td></tr>";
```